# How can I assign a function to cdkDragData and then call that function as a callback while dragging?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8, angular-cdk-drag-drop

My drag has been implemented in a separate component and drop in another component.While dragging, I call [cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="isDropPossible" and I have to use a callback inside this "isDropPossible" function. This callback function will be nothing but the function that I will assign to the cdkDragData in the drag component, and this only handles whether a drop can happen inside a container or not. How will or how can I assign a function to cdkDragData is my question!!!

Drop component:(where callback needs to be made)

```
  <mondrian-widget [model]="elementModel" [showDragger]="isPageModificationMode" id="{{elementModel.vid}}"
    cdkDropList  [cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="isDragPossible"></mondrian-widget>
```

Drag Container

```
 <div cdkDrag class="metric-container" data-cy="metricContainer" (cdkDragDropped)="dragDropped($event, field)"
  [cdkDragData]="field"> /* field is the name of the function i want to assign, but its not working.I am able to only assign a variable to it, and not a function!!!
```